# Menu in Drupal8

Tags: 8, routes, navigation

I am currently using below code to generate routes:

```
foreach($this->hardcopyEntityManager->getHardcopyEntities() as $entity_type => $entity_definition)
 {

      $route = new Route(

        "/$entity_type/{entity}/hardcopy/{hardcopy_format}",

        array(
          '_controller' => 'Drupal\hardcopy\Controller\HardcopyController::showFormat',
          '_title' => 'Hardcopy',
        ),

        array(
          '_permission' => 'view printer friendly versions',
        ),

        array(
          'parameters' => array(
            'entity' => array('type' => 'entity:' . $entity_type),
          ),
        )
      );

      $collection->add('hardcopy.show_format.' . $entity_type, $route);
    }
```

But if now I want to make the same route using *.routing.yml file then how will I be proceeding? Assuming the entity type to be node.

Comment: [The docs](https://www.drupal.org/node/2092643) are pretty clear, which part you stuck at specifically? Can you post the contents of your routing file so far and point out which bit isn't working/you don't know how to continue with?

Comment: I am confused how to implement this part: array(
      'parameters' => array(
        'entity' => array('type' => 'entity:' . $entity_type),
      ),
    ) . I am not sure how to do this.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
# This should be entity.node.hardcopy, also altering node link templates could be good idea
hardcopy.show_format.node:
  path: '/node/{node}/hardcopy/{hardcopy_format}'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\hardcopy\Controller\HardcopyController::showFormat'
    _title: 'Hardcopy'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'view printer friendly versions'
```